# android studio permissions for image upload

Tags: android, image, bitmap

these errors are appearing inside android studio:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {info.adreamcatcherp.android/info.adreamcatcherp.android.pic}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

The entire project worked before I altered permissions, now I can not find the permission arrangement. This is what I have, for some reason the image upload just isn't being accepted by the application anymore:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="www.placeprint.xyz"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="7.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!-- Internet permission -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"

        />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <android:uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <android:uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
```

Comment: you have included permissions properly...as you can see error is **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference** that is NullPointerException in your activity...please debug it

Comment: Actually Shadow, they were not implemented properly. READ and WRITE needed to be placed above the android hardware camera feature.

Comment: you should never downvote without explaining why.

Answer (score 3):

The answer, include this in android manifest, READ and WRITE needed to be placed above the android hardware camera feature.:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   <!-- Internet permission -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"

    />
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html in your code to so the user can also allow permission along with having WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" I your manifest

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```